# Understanding output of "ip route get"

Tags: routing, linux

My routing table looks as below:

```
[root@master ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.31.16.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.31.16.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.189.64  172.31.23.103   255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
192.168.219.64  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
192.168.235.128 172.31.21.191   255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 tunl0
[root@master ~]#
```

I need help to understand output of the below command:

```
[root@master ~]# ip route get 192.168.235.131
192.168.235.131 via 172.31.21.191 dev tunl0 src 192.168.219.64
    cache
[root@master ~]#
```

Here, I understand that in order to go to `192.168.235.131`, the next hop is `172.31.21.191` based upon the routing table.

However, what do we mean by `dev tunl0 src 192.168.219.64?`

Comment: Unfortunately, question about hosts/servers are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 1):

> what do we mean by `dev tunl0 src 192.168.219.64`?

`tunl0` is the egress interface towards the gateway (as indicated in the routing table above) and `192.168.219.64` is the local address assumed as source (looks like a loopback interface, likely the default).

Since routing can also be based on policies (PBR), you can specify a source address and `ip route get` then tells you which route a supposed packet would take.

Comment: can you please help understand how does `egress interface` differs from the `etho` interface?

Comment: Most likely, `eth0` is a physical interface and `tunl0` is a virtual tunnel interface. The *egress interface* is the one that the packet needs to be sent out with.